# Radcombobox clears the text when it is not in the items list

Tags: wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I have a telerik's `radcombobox` like below:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cbCustomerName"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                 Margin="0 0 0 10"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                                 IsEditable="True"
                                 IsFilteringEnabled="True"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                                 OpenDropDownOnFocus="True"
                                 SelectedValuePath="CustomerId"
                                 SelectionChanged="cbCustomerName_SelectionChanged"
                                 Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.FullName,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

When I type something in the textbox that is not in its items list and then go to some other control, it clears the text in it, which I don't want.

I have checked all properties and couldn't find anything to retain it after losing focus.

Please help if anyone knows about this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I figured I'd post a solution in case anyone else has this issue. If you set the "IsTextSearchEnabled" property to "False", it allows custom text and doesn't clear it when the RadComboBox loses focus.

Comment: If we add this then user cannot search the items in the combobox, here we want user should able to search and if it wont find in the list the text should also be there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `AllowCustomText` Property to true?

Comment: There is no `AllowCustomText` property in this.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice it was WPF telerik

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `TextSearchMode="Contains"`. Either that or try removing `IsFilteringEnabled="True"` if you do not need to filter your results.
I am not 100% sure, but it may clear your text if you try and filter it and it does not find anything.